# Why don't multiple Titanium.App.fireEvent() calls work in Android from Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: javascript, android, events, titanium, appcelerator

In Titanium Appcelerator, I have a project that creates a tabGroup and window via a function.

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('startCoSelect', function(e) {
    // store user name and password globally
    // user = e.user;
    // pass = e.pass;
    tabs.close();
    tabs = tms.ui.createCoSelectGroup();
    tabs.open();
});

Ti.App.addEventListener('startAppHome', function(e) {
    tabs.close();
    tabs = tms.ui.createApplicationTabGroup();
    tabs.open();
});

var tabs = tms.security.getPermission();
tabs.open();
```

Within this function is a button, this button has an event listener assigned to it that then calls Ti.App.fireEvent('startCoSelect').

```
    btnLogin.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        Ti.App.fireEvent('startCoSelect');
    });
```

From this event listener a function is called that opens a new tabGroup and window as well as closing the previous tab group as shown above. Inside of the tabGroup created by tms.ui.createCoSelectGroup() is another eventlistener that fires another event

```
    btnSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        Ti.App.fireEvent('startAppHome');
    });
```

and once again another event listener and fireEvent call within the tms.ui.createApplicationTabGroup() function.

I am developing and testing all code within Titanium Studio with Titanium sdk 1.7 using the continuous/nightly builds of both on Mac OS X 10 as well as a completely updated Android and iOS sdk.

My issue is only within Android. The mobile app works perfectly as it should on iPhone. However, on Android (testing with 2.2 API's emulator) I can only fire one event. As an example, the android application will accept the first button "click" event fine and fire the event but then the next fireEvent call (activated by the next button press) will not fire.

I know that the "click" event is firing, by placing an alert inside of each Event Listener, and that it has to be the fireEvent call.

I also know that it doesn't have anything to do with the order of the calls. If I change which event is fired first it will always fire the first one and it will always refuse the fireEvent calls that follow. An example being that I changed which tabGroup and window was opened at launch and the first button click and fireEvent work then afterwards, even though the next click events are registered, the fireEvent call is not.

The Trace and console give no answers or error codes and I am left with only a button that does nothing unless I place an alert or function inside. I have tried having the function call Ti.App.fireEvent() and it doesn't change.

I may be able to post code via pastie but I need to remove crucial information before posting it so it may take a day.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: just curious why you implemented it this way, and why you are using the continuos builds?

Comment: Ah Aaron, I'm a fan of your blog. I implemented it this way because of scope and trying to protect data. It seems messy here but if I am able to show the code it comes together clearly.

The continuous builds were because I noticed an error was coming up with fireEvent in older builds and wanted to make sure it wasn't another build I tried the release candidate and the 3 most current up to today's build.

Comment: Alright, I have discovered that it has something to do with closing the tabGroup from within the Event listener. I believe it might be because the event was fired from the tabGroup that is closing. I have an idea why, but it is only an opinion and it would be great if someone could explain why as an actual answer. The application now works but I would still like an answer. Thank You.

Comment: Could You please tell me how you fix it, because I have the same issue. Thanks, Karl

Comment: Do you get any exception in the console?